# clustalw and muscle in Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I am having problem using biopython,I have Python version
 v3.3 and I  installed biopython-1.61.win-amd64-py3.3
I want to align DNA sequences with `Clustalw` or `Muscle`

for `Clustalw:`

```
from Bio.Clustalw import MultipleAlignCL
```

I get the following error:

```
No module named 'Bio.Clustalw'
```

for `Muscle:`

```
>>> from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
>>> muscle_cline = MuscleCommandline(input="input.fasta")
>>> stdout, stderr = muscle_cline()
```

I get the following error:

```
stdout, stderr = muscle_cline()
  File "..\..\lib\site-packages\Bio\Application\__init__.py", line 434, in __call__
    shell=(sys.platform!="win32"))
  File "..:\..\lib\subprocess.py", line 818, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "..:\..\lib\subprocess.py", line 1096, in _execute_child
    raise WindowsError(*e.args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file is not found
```

Comment: Can I check first that you have installed muscle and clustalw? (Clustal Omega is the latest version of clustal, you may wish to use that for faster alignments.)

Comment: No,I haven't installed muscle and clustalw

Comment: Got it. You will need to install those two programs. BioPython doesn't provide those programs, it only provides wrappers to access those programs. My guess is that once you've installed those programs, the errors will either change or go away.

Answer (score 2):

First, try installing Biopython 1.63 from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#biopython), it may solve some of your problems.

Second, make sure you're using [the latest Python](http://python.org/download) from python.org - you might want to run the installer again just to ensure that none of your files are corrupted, if you're still getting the same error after updating Biopython.

---

I found [this](http://www.biopython.org/DIST/docs/_api_158/Bio.Clustalw-module.html) that indicates that `Bio.Clustalw` is deprecated.

> This module has been superseded by the Bio.AlignIO framework for
>   alignment parsing, and the ClustalW command line wrapper in
>   Bio.Align.Applications for calling the tool. These are both described
>   in the current version of the Biopython Tutorial and Cookbook.

so that explains that. As for `Bio.Align.Applications.MuscleCommandLine`, running `help()` on it gave the following code example:

```
>>> from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
>>> muscle_exe = r"C:\Program Files\Aligments\muscle3.8.31_i86win32.exe"
>>> in_file = r"C:\My Documents\unaligned.fasta"
>>> out_file = r"C:\My Documents\aligned.fasta"
>>> muscle_cline = MuscleCommandline(muscle_exe, input=in_file, out=out_file)
>>> print(muscle_cline)
"C:\Program Files\Aligments\muscle3.8.31_i86win32.exe" -in "C:\My Documents\unaligned.fasta" -out "C:\My Documents\aligned.fasta"
```

So, your error is indicating that a proper `muscle.exe` wasn't found, so you'd need to pass its location as a parameter.